# Несколько DrawPanel

Tags: java, swing

Здравствуйте.

Есть код игры в лабиринт. Я хочу перенести часть кода отвечающего за передвижение в класс Player, как это сделано с методом moveRight(). Вместе с этим придется вызвать перерисовку сразу в классе Player, но возникла проблема в 19 строчке класса Player. Я пытаюсь создать панель для рисования и заново нарисовать квадрат, но с уже новыми координатами. 
Вот сама ошибка:

> Error:(20, 23) java: cannot find symbol symbol: class MyDrawPanel
>   location: class Player

Как можно её решить?

Класс RealMaze, он же главный:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

/**
 * В этой программе осуществляется движение по лабиринту.
 * Передвигаться нужно с помощью стрелок.
 */

public class RealMaze implements KeyListener {

    //Начальные координаты игрока.

    public static int X = 0;
    public static int Y = 0;

    JFrame frame;
    Player player = new Player();
    MyDrawPanel myDrawPanel = new MyDrawPanel();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        RealMaze realMaze = new RealMaze();
        realMaze.go();
    }

    public void go()throws Exception {

        //Отрисовка окна

        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(new MyDrawPanel());
        frame.setSize(500, 560);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, myDrawPanel);
        frame.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/IP44/Downloads/thinWall2.png")));
        frame.addKeyListener(this);

    }

    //Перемещение по массиву.

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        try {
            int key = e.getKeyCode();

            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
                player.moveRight();

            }

            if (Map.map[X][Y] == 0 && e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
                X--;
                if (Map.map[X][Y] == 2) {
                    X--;
                }
            }

            if (Map.map[X][Y] == 0 && e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
                Y--;
                if (Map.map[X][Y] == 2) {
                    Y--;
                }
            }

            if (Map.map[X][Y] == 0 && e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
                Y++;
                if (Map.map[X][Y] == 2) {
                    Y++;
                }
            }

            if (Map.map[X][Y] == 0 && e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE) {
                System.exit(0);
            }

            frame.repaint();
        } catch (Exception ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)   {
    }
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    //Перемещение по фрейму.

    class MyDrawPanel extends JPanel {
        public  void paintComponent(Graphics g)   {
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            int sideLength = 70;
            g.fillRect(X*70, Y*70, 70, 70);
        }
    }
}
```

Класс Player.

```
/**
 * Класс, в который планируется перенести
 * передвижение игрока.
 */

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

class Player extends JPanel {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    public static int X = 0;
    public static int Y = 0;


    public void moveRight() {

        //Перемещение по массиву.
        frame.add(new MyDrawPanel()); //Ошибка

        if (Map.map[X][Y] == 0) {
            X++;
            if (Map.map[X][Y] == 2) {
                X++;
            }
        }

        //Метод вызывается, так как значение X при каждом нажатии увеличивается.
        System.out.println("Новое значение Х = " + X);

        //Перемещение по фрейму.
        class MyDrawPanel extends JPanel {
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g)   {
                g.setColor(Color.red);
                g.fillRect(X * 70, Y * 70, 70, 70);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Класс Map.

```
/**
 * Класс, для хранения карты передвижения.
 * Карта передвижения, 1 - стена, 2 - тонкая стена
 */
public class Map {
    static int[][] map = new int[][]{
            {0,0,2,0,0,0,0}, //x
            {0,0,2,0,0,0,0}, //|
            {0,0,1,0,0,0,0}, //|
            {0,0,1,1,2,2,2}, //|
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0}, //|
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0}, //|
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0}  //|
            // - - - - - y
    };
}
```